# How to uncheck all rows using UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark

Tags: iphone, xcode, checkmark

I've got a `UITableView` with each row containing a checkbox using `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`. I can't figure out how to uncheck all the checkboxes using the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  

    UITableViewCell *oldCell;

    int count = [self.myTableRowNamesArray count];

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {                                
        // Uncheck all checkboxes
        // OF COURSE THIS DOESN'T WORK
        // BECAUSE i IS AN INTEGER AND INDEXPATH IS A POINTER
        FOO: oldCell = [myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(int)i];
        // GOOD CODE:
        oldCell = [penanceOptionsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
        oldCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    UITableViewCell *newCell = [myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` uses `NSIndexPath` instead of integer so make indexpath by using

```
indexPathForRow:inSection:
```

if you are using one section then your loop is fine just pass i in row and 0 for section.

Answer (score 20):

Instead of modifying the `.accessoryType` of all cells in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, I suggest **storing the selected index** in some ivar, and change the `.accessoryType` in the data source's `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, i.e.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath { 
   self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
   [tableView reloadData];
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
   ...
   cell.accessoryType = [indexPath compare:self.selectedIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame
                          ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark
                          : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
   ...
}
```

With this, only visible cells will be affected, and the million other cells outside of the screen won't need to be modified.

---

*Quite right, here's a full implementation in Swift in the general case of selecting a cell .. you'd use selectedIndexPath elsewhere in the class as you see fit. For example, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to choose the appropriate cell prototype.*

```
//  SelectingTableViewController

import UIKit

class SelectingTableViewController: UITableViewController   
    {
    internal var selectedIndexPath:NSIndexPath? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad()
        {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 68.0
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false;
        }

    override func tableView
        (tableView:UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath)
            {
            print("did select....")

            // in fact, was this very row selected,
            // and the user is clicking to deselect it...
            // if you don't want "click a selected row to deselect"
            // then on't include this clause.
            if selectedIndexPath == indexPath
                {
                print("(user clicked on selected to deselect)")
                selectedIndexPath = nil
                tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(
                    [indexPath],
                    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimation.None)

                tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated:false)
                return
                }

            // in fact, was some other row selected??
            // user is changing to this row? if so, also deselect that row
            if selectedIndexPath != nil
                {
                let pleaseRedrawMe = selectedIndexPath!
                // (note that it will be drawn un-selected
                // since we're chaging the 'selectedIndexPath' global)
                selectedIndexPath = indexPath
                tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(
                    [pleaseRedrawMe, indexPath],
                    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
                return;
                }

            // no previous selection.
            // simply select that new one the user just touched.
            // note that you can not use Apple's willDeselectRowAtIndexPath
            // functions ... because they are freaky
            selectedIndexPath = indexPath
            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(
                [indexPath],
                withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimation.None)

            }

    }
```

Comment: does calling [reloadData] multiple times cause any bad effect ?

Answer (score 11):

```
for (UITableViewCell *cell in [myTableView visibleCells]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

But really, you'd be better off just modifying the one cell that actually has the checkmark set. You have to have stored this information somewhere in your model anyway.

Comment: That's what I mean. Just change the one cell that has the checkmark set (and of course the cell that is becoming the new checked cell).

Answer (score 5):

You're probably setting some kind of property with this method. 
So what i do is:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // 1. first unsetting the property
    [object someProperty:nil];

    // 2. call the reloadData method to uncheck all the checkmarks
    [tableView reloadData];

    // 3. check the selected cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

    // 4. set the checked property
    [object setSomeProperty:[indexpath row]];
}
```

And in my cellForRowAtIndexPath methods i got something like the following code:

```
    if([object someProperty] == [indexpath row]){
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];        
    } else {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }
```