# Swift Allow selection of only one cell

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I have a working UITableview which currently allows multiple Cells to be selected. I would like just one to be selected and if a previous one was chosen then the new selection should uncheck the previous one. Mind bender! Here is my code:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();
    let CurrentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!;

    if CurrentCell.imageView!.image == nil {
        let SelectedCell = CurrentCell.textLabel!.text
        CurrentCell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named:"check")!
        CurrentCell.textLabel!.font = UIFont(name:"OpenSans-Bold", size:15)
        println("Selected Cell is")
        println(SelectedCell)
    } else {
        CurrentCell.imageView!.image = nil
        let SelectedCell = "NothingSelected"
        CurrentCell.textLabel!.font = UIFont(name:"OpenSans-Regular", size:15)    
        println("Nothing Selected")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you set the "allowsMultipleSelection" flag to NO ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very effective way to manage the selection state is to add a `selected` property to the data model, in this example just called `Model`

```
class Model {

  var selected = false

  ...
}
```

---

In the `UITableViewController` class we assume there is an Array `data` which holds the `Model` items as the data source for the table view.

```
var data = [Model]()
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` set the image and text depending on the `selected` property:

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyIdentifier") as! UITableViewCell
    let currentItem = data[indexPath.row]
    if currentItem.selected {
      cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named:"check")!
      cell.textLabel!.font = UIFont(name:"OpenSans-Bold", size:15)
    } else {
      cell.imageView!.image = nil
      cell.textLabel!.font = UIFont(name:"OpenSans-Regular", size:15)
    }

    return cell
  }
```

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` set the property `selected` of the currently selected  cells to false, set the property `selected` of the just selected cell to true and reload the table, the changes are applied in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    data.filter {$0.selected == true}.map {$0.selected = false}
    let currentItem = data[indexPath.row]
    currentItem.selected = true
    tableView.reloadData()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create your instance var to keep your selection index

and then in your cellForINdexPath method check if the current cell is equals to it:

that was discussed here:
[How to uncheck all rows using UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541328/how-to-uncheck-all-rows-using-uitableviewcellaccessorycheckmark)